# $\cos \alpha+\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha+2\beta)+.....+\cos(\alpha+(n-1)\beta)=0 $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polygons

If each side of a regular polygon of $n$ sides subtend an angle $\alpha$ at the center of the polygon and each exterior angle of the polygon is $\beta$,then prove that $\cos \alpha+\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha+2\beta)+.....+\cos(\alpha+(n-1)\beta)=0 $

Since this is a regular polygon.Therefore,each $\alpha=\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and since each external angle is $\beta$.So by geometry,$\alpha=\beta.$

$\cos \alpha+\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha+2\beta)+.....+\cos(\alpha+(n-1)\beta)=\frac{\cos\frac{n\beta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\beta}{2}}\cos\frac{2\alpha+(n-1)\beta}{2}$

Now putting $\alpha=\beta=\frac{2\pi}{n}$ does not give me answer.What mistake did i make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in the summation formula. Here is a correct version:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos (\alpha+\beta j)=\frac{ \sin \left(\frac{n \beta
   }{2}\right) }{\sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)}\cos \left(\alpha+\frac{1}{2} (n   -1
   )\beta\right).$$

This clearly helps to establish your result.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, in a regular polygon with $n$ number of side,

the angle subtended by each side at the center of the polygon $$\alpha=\frac{2\pi}{n}$$

each exterior angle of the polygon $$\beta=\pi-\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}=\frac{2\pi}{n}$$

$$\implies \alpha=\beta=\frac{2\pi}{n}$$  Now, we have 
$$\cos \alpha+\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha+2\beta)+\ldots +\cos(\alpha+(n-1)\beta)$$ setting $\beta=\alpha$
$$=\cos \alpha+\cos(\alpha+\alpha)+\cos(\alpha+2\alpha)+\ldots +\cos(\alpha+(n-1)\alpha)$$
$$=\cos \alpha+\cos(2\alpha)+\cos(3\alpha)+\ldots +\cos(n\alpha)$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin n\alpha\cot\frac{\alpha}{2}+\cos n\alpha-1\right]$$
Setting $\alpha=\frac{2\pi}{n}$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin n\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\cot\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\cos n\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)-1\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin 2\pi\cot\frac{\pi}{n}+\cos 2\pi-1\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left[0+1-1\right]=0$$ Hence, proved that

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\cos \alpha+\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha+2\beta)+\ldots +\cos(\alpha+(n-1)\beta)=\color{blue}{0}}}$$

Comment: how did $\cos \alpha+\cos 2\alpha+\cos 3\alpha+.....+\cos n\alpha=\frac{1}{2}[\sin n\alpha+\cos n\alpha-1]$ come,did not get?

Comment: Alright, there was some error I have corrected. There is a general formula for sum of cosines of angles in A.P.  $$\cos\theta+\cos 2\theta+\cos 3\theta+\ldots+\cos(n-1)\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin n\theta\cot\frac{\theta}{2}-\cos n\theta-1\right]$$ If there are $n$ terms then the sum is given as  $$\cos\theta+\cos 2\theta+\cos 3\theta+\ldots+\cos n\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin n\theta\cot\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos n\theta-1\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the displayed "identity" is wrong. If you put $\alpha=\beta=0$, the left hand side is $n$, but the right hand side is $1$.

**Edit.** As pointed out by Math-fun in the other answer, you have apparently memorised the sum-of-angle formula wrongly. Alternatively, by De Moivre's formula, the sum in question is equal to the real part of
$$
S=e^{i\alpha}(1+e^{i\beta}+e^{2i\beta}+\ldots+e^{(n-1)i\beta}).
$$
Sum up the geometric sequence and put $\beta=\frac{2\pi}n$, you will see that $S$ and in turn its real part are zero.

Comment: Maybe $\alpha=\beta=0$ is a special case?

Comment: @picasso What do you mean? When the denominator is defined, the RHS is continuous. So, as the purported "identity" doesn't hold at $\alpha=\beta=0$, it also doesn't hold when $\alpha,\beta$ are close to zero. Since the equality doesn't hold for infinitely many case, it can hardly be called an identity.

Comment: @picasso see a corrected identity above :-)

Comment: Ah yes @user1551. I missed the $\equiv$ part ! In fact I didn't see the word "identity" anywhere in the question. I guess it's implied by the context.